# Use case for change detection when requestAnimationFrame is called

Tags: angular, performance, requestanimationframe, angular-changedetection

In an Angular-App I had an issue with a third party library that is heavily using `requestAnimationFrame`, which in return triggers a lot of change detection cycles.

While this not necessarily leads to bigger performance issues, it still seems unnecessary to me. On top of that it causes a lot of noice in the angular dev-tools profiler.

Some research brought up that I can tell zone.js to deactivate the monkey-patch for `requestAnimationFrame`:

`(window as any).__Zone_disable_requestAnimationFrame = true;`

Well, this works, but it makes me wonder if someone working with this app in the future might hit her hard hard when relying on zone.js doing its job, without knowing that I partially disabled it.

To better understand the impact of this decision I'd like to better understand actual usecases where a call to `requestAnimationFrame` might alter the applications state and thus require change detection to run.